# Переадресация с продвинутого домена на новый

Tags: seo

У меня есть 2 домена одной тематики, один из них хорошо продвинулся в сео, но сайт там не вах. Хочу вложить все силы в развитие сайта на другом домене и сделать 301 переадресацию с главной страницы первого сайта на второй. Готов пожертвовать контентом первого сайта, чтобы уже вновь приходящие пользователи регистрировались на втором.

Как это воспримут поисковые системы? Что будет с позициями первого сайта после такого?